# passing an URL to owslib in Qgis editor doesn't work properly?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-python-console, owslib

I'm trying to determine the version number of several WFS using the python module owslib. 
since i need to use this version number in ogr2ogr (and for some reason, python's ogr2ogr only works in Qgis' editor), i am runnign this in Qgis 3.2's python editor window.

This has been working fine for around 5-6 wfs urls (both with http and https). however when i get to the url: 
https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS

the code:

```
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService as wfsmod
url = "https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS"
wfs = wfsmod(url)
```

crashes and returns:

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS%C2%A0+&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.0.0

I have tried the code both in the python console in qgis 3.2 and in a seperate python IDE. It works there without crashing.  But as said, i need to run this in the **editor** because this snippet is part of a larger code, which doesn't function in the IDE and the python console window in qgis.

Comment: To determine the highest supported version of any OGC interface standard (WMS/WFS/WCS..) send a GetCapabilities request without version, for you like: `https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities`.

Comment: The base URL you use should be the URL for the service without any request parameters so for you just `https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer?`

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need some code like:

```
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService as wfsmod

url = "https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer?"
try:
    wfs = wfsmod(url, version='2.0.0')
except ExplicitException:
    try:
         wfs = wfsmod(url, version='1.1.0')
    except ExplicitException:
        try:
            wfs = wfsmod(url, version='1.0.0')
        except ExplicitException:
            pass
finally:
    # do something
```